AFM assylum research .ibw file- Data Plot
I am trying to plot data from assylum research software for AFM scanning. All files are .ibw type. I am trying it on Matlab. No matter what I do Matlab can't open data of the Ibw files. I am using Mac Os. How to solve this issue?
Put them in to your Matlab folder and add path to them in Matlab.
Function call:
a=IBWread(b);

Where b is path to the ibw file.
Cite As
Jakub Bialek (2024). Igor Pro file format (ibw) to matlab variable (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42679-igor-pro-file-format-ibw-to-matlab-variable), MATLAB Central File Exchange. Retrieved July 7, 2024.

This is what I tried but when I try to select file in my Mac there is no way I can select any files!
